Appears errors : element invalid
The code: it's appears element invalid but idk : so, how appears error:
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native' import { SplashScreen, Stack , Sta} from 'expo-router'; import { useFonts } from "expo-font"; import { useEffect } from 'react';   // import GlobalProvider from '../context/GlobalProvider'  SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync(); const RootLayout = () =\> {   const \[fontsLoaded, error\] = useFonts({     "Poppins-Black": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf"),     "Poppins-Bold": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"),     "Poppins-ExtraBold": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf"),     "Poppins-ExtraLight": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf"),     "Poppins-Light": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf"),     "Poppins-Medium": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf"),     "Poppins-Regular": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),     "Poppins-SemiBold": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"),     "Poppins-Thin": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Thin.ttf"),   });    useEffect(() =\> {     if (error) throw error;      if (fontsLoaded) {       SplashScreen.hideAsync();     }   }, \[fontsLoaded, error\]);    if (!fontsLoaded) {     return null;   }    if (!fontsLoaded && !error) {     return null;   }    return (      \<Stack.Navigator\>          \<Stack\>     \<Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} /\>     \<Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ headerShown: false }} /\>     \<Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} /\>     \<Stack.Screen name="procura/\[query\]" options={{ headerShown: false }} /\>   \</Stack\>   \</Stack.Navigator\>     ) } export default RootLayout; // Make sure to export the component

i get this error, but teh code seems fine
everthing looks fine

could you add the code to your question?

I guess its that "sta" in the expo-router import. Try removing that and it should work fine.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
